# scandir in c - sel function implementation

Tags: c, scandir

`man scandir` gives me a following structure of the `scandir` function:

```
int scandir(const char *dirp, struct dirent ***namelist,
              int (*filter)(const struct dirent *),
              int (*compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));
```

Suppose I define the following:

```
struct dirent **namelist;
int len = scandir('.', &namelist, NULL, NULL)
```

this lists all the files and folder names in the current folder. But suppose I have a `filter` and `compar` function of the following structure:

```
int (*filter)(const struct dirent *) {
}
```

and similar for compar, and I want to call this filter function or just `NULL` based on some criteria:

```
if (some criteria) int *filters = NULL;
else int* filters = &filter
int len = scandir('.', &namelist, filters, NULL)
```

but this gives pointer error. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: "this gives pointer error": can you share the exact error message instead? during compilation? during execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `filter` is a function pointer, not an int pointer.
2. In your code, `filter` is locally scoped to the if else block, which is wrong.

Working code would look something like:

```
int nodots(const struct dirent *dp)
{
    return (dp->d_name[0] != '.');
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct dirent **entries;
  ...
  int (*myfilter)(const struct dirent *) = NULL;
  if(some_condition) myfilter = nodots;
  ...
  nents = scandir(".", &entries, myfilter, alphasort);
}
```